# set value inside embedded object using java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

i am  having object like `List<taskDetail> taskDetails` and `TaskDetail DTO` like

```
    public class TaskDetail {

        private Task task ;

        private int taskId;

        private int taskDetailId;

        private String status;
        ...
    }
```

And `Task DTO` is like

```
   public class Task{
       private int taskId;

       private int totalActive;

       .....
     }
```

so i have to check all entries inside `taskDetails` and get total no of counts against `taskId` which are `ACTIVE` as status and set inside `task's totalActive` object having matching `taskId` inside `embedded task object` inside `taskDetails` . I am able to do so using java7 , but stuck in using java8.

I am using `Map` and storing `taskId` as key

```
  Map<Integer,Integer> myTaskMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
  taskDetails.forEach(taskEdt->{
                int count =myTaskMap.get(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId());
                if(taskEdt.getStatus() == Status.ACTIVE) {
                coun>0? myTaskMap.put(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId(), count+1);:myTaskMap.put(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId(), 1)
                }
            });


taskDetails.forEach(taskEdt->{
                if(null !=myTaskMap.get(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId())) {
                    taskEdt.getTask().setTotalActive(myTaskMap.get(taskEdt.getTask().geTaskId()));
                }
            });
```

and again in `ForEach` setting value from map inside `Task;s totalActive` object inside `taskDetails` .

Comment: Can you show your java-7 approach?

Comment: @user7 see the edits

Comment: @SunilGoyal Do complete the code with what do you mean by *and again in ForEach setting value from map inside Task;s totalActive object inside taskDetails*, would make some sense out of the question then.

Answer (score 1):

First, we stream the task details list filtering only the ACTIVE ones. Then, group by the `taskId` to create a mapping of the taskId to the list of `TaskDetails` for that taskId. This would also give us the number of `TaskDetails` for a given taskId (which is the length of the list).

Then, we run through it and update the TaskDetails' Task's `totalActive` by inferring the `totalActive` as the length of the list.
(Assuming you have a setter)

```
Map<Integer, List<TaskDetail>> taskIdToTaskDetailsList = taskDetails.stream()
            .filter(taskDetail -> taskDetail.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TaskDetail::getTaskId));

taskIdToTaskDetailsList.values()
            .forEach(listOfTaskDetails -> listOfTaskDetails
                    .forEach(taskDetail -> taskDetail.getTask()
                            .setTotalActive(listOfTaskDetails.size())));
```

*Note:* For this to work correctly, the `taskId` in the `TaskDetail` must match the `taskId` of the `task` field.

Answer (score 0):

Though the mutation along with streams is something I would suggest not practicing but a way to do what you intend could possibly using `counting` (or `reduce`) and further with filter updating the list as :

```
Map<Integer, Integer> myTaskMap = taskDetails.stream()
        .filter(taskEdt -> taskEdt.getStatus().equals("ACTIVE"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(taskEdt -> taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId(),
                Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));
taskDetails.stream()
        .filter(taskEdt -> myTaskMap.containsKey(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId()))
        .forEach(taskEdt -> taskEdt.getTask().setTotalActive(
                myTaskMap.get(taskEdt.getTask().getTaskId())));
```